# What method will be called when execute a po command

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata, lldb, ios13

I used thought that when i execute a po command in lldb ,e.g

po nsdataObject

the nsdataObject's description method will be called .

But in iOS13 ，if i po a nsdataObject it will print all bytes.

```
(lldb) po profileData
<308225c8 06092a86 4886f70d 010702a0 8225b930 8225b502 0101310b 30090605 2b0e0302 1a050030 82155c06 092a8648 86f70d01 0701a082 154d0482 15493c3f 786d6c20 76657273 696f6e3d 22312e30 2220656e 636f6469 6e673d22 5554462d 38223f3e 0a3c2144 4f435459 50452070 6c697374 20505542 4c494320 222d2f2f 4170706c 652f2f44 54442050 4c495354 20312e30 2f2f454e 22202268 7474703a 2f2f7777 772e6170 706c652e 636f6d2f 44544473 2f50726f 70657274 794c6973 742d312e 302e6474 64223e0a 3c706c69 73742076 65727369 6f6e3d22 312e3022 3e0a3c64 6963743e 0a093c6b 65793e41 70704944 4e616d65 3c2f6b65 793e0a09 3c737472 696e673e 4b4d4465 6275673c 2f737472 696e673e 0a093c6b 65793e41 70706c69 63617469 6f6e4964 656e7469 66696572 50726566 69783c2f 6b65793e 0a093c61 72726179 3e0a093c 73747269 6e673e50 59323838 4e353639 383c2f73 7472696e 673e0a09 3c2f6172 7261793e 0a093c6b 65793e43 72656174 696f6e44 6174653c 2f6b6579 3e0a093c 64617465 3e323031 392d3037 2d323454 30313a35 343a3236 5a3c2f64 6174653e 0a093c6b 65793e50 6c617466 6f726d3c 2f6b6579
```

And if i execute [nsdataObject description] it will output like this:

```
(lldb) po [profileData description]
{length = 9676, bytes = 0x308225c8 06092a86 4886f70d 010702a0 ... 0377b724 11c4283f }
```

In iOS12 and before , both of them will output like the 1st po object command. And can i call some method of the object to get the exactly the same output with the 1st po command ?

Comment: OK,seems the debugDescription works for me,and the po command calls debugDescription not the description , am I rignt?

Comment: The po command in lldb (for ObjC) actually calls a Foundation function: `_NSPrintForDebugger`.  That function calls `debugDescription` if the object responds to the selector, and falls back to `description` if it doesn't.